# how run a video from folder`s Video in my project in WPF,not out of project?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, wpf-controls

i have a project WPF,i want run a video.i success run a video,but i want to address within project,rather than outside,
For example,i want:

```
    <MediaElement Name="redangVideo" Source="Videos\clip.avi" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
```

not:

```
 <MediaElement Name="redangVideo" Source="C:\path_file\Videos\clip.avi" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **.xaml** assuming your *Videos* folder at the root position

```
<MediaElement Name="redangVideo" Source="/Videos/clip.avi" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
```

For **.cs** : codebehind

```
redangVideo.Source = "pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Videos/clip.avi";
```

Comment: what is AssemblyName and application?

Comment: This is the [_link_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) on MSDN for detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

assume you have this file **video.avi** in your project (name it **MyControls**) in **InnerFolder** directory, then use this method:

```
MediaElement getMedia()
    {
        MediaElement m= new MediaElement();
        m.Source = new MediaElement(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyControls;component/InnerFolder/video.avi"));
        return m;
    }
```